# JPA mapping failing on strange message

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, hibernate-mapping

I have a strange problem where the JPA mapping is failing on converting to a timestamp, but the value it's using appears to be the entire row, not just one variable.

The error is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Value '1988├╗  ├╗├╗├╗├╗├╗├╗0
07 1234567 wk├╗0├╗├╗├╗├╗├╗                                              ' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp
```

where the value seems to be the entire row, with most of the bad characters being nulls. Debug logging isn't giving me much at the moment, and I'm not sure whether it's an error in my mapping class, collation issues, or something else.

MySQL workbench reads all the information from the table correctly. Running mysql from the command outputs all the data correctly. Neither show any special characters anywhere.

A simplified version of my mapping class is:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class PersonSundry {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="person_id", unique=true)
    private Person person;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Lookup1 lookup1;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Lookup2 lookup2;

    @Lob
    private String backgroundInfo;
    private LocalDate dateOfSomething1;
    private LocalDate dateOfSomething2;
    private LocalDate dateOfSomething3;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Has anyone come across this before? Any ideas where else to look?

EDIT: The root cause turned out to be a generic failed cast of 00-00-0000 to a timestamp, however I'm going to leave the question open to see if someone knows where the strange error message was given instead of an exact one.

Comment: User performs some operation, and SQL is sent to the database. That SQL is printed in the JPA provider log. Why not look at it?

Comment: Have you added Java 8 support for Hibernate? Because JPA 2.1 does not support java 8 date time api out of the box

Comment: Can you show the code how you persist (if you persist in java) & find the failing row(s)? What is the datatype of LocalDate in database?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, this is on reading from the database, not persisting to it. The problem ended up being reading a 00-00-0000 date, but I'm going to leave the question open as the error message is strange

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MYSQL?
Please try using this type of connection string.

```
jdbc:mysql://yourserver:3306/yourdatabase?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

Datetimes with all-zero components (0000-00-00 ...) — These values can not be represented reliably in Java. Connector/J 3.0.x always converted them to NULL when being read from a ResultSet.

Connector/J 3.1 throws an exception by default when these values are encountered as this is the most correct behavior according to the JDBC and SQL standards. This behavior can be modified using the zeroDateTimeBehavior configuration property. The allowable values are:

exception (the default), which throws an SQLException with an SQLState of S1009.

convertToNull, which returns NULL instead of the date.

round, which rounds the date to the nearest closest value which is 0001-01-01.

Comment: This handles causes MySQL to do the conversions implicitly. What I'd like to know though is why is the error message is incorrect.

Comment: Datetimes with all-zero components (0000-00-00 ...) — These values can not be represented reliably in Java. Connector/J 3.0.x always converted them to NULL when being read from a ResultSet.

Connector/J 3.1 throws an exception by default when these values are encountered as this is the most correct behavior according to the JDBC and SQL standards. This behavior can be modified using the zeroDateTimeBehavior configuration property.